# Tensorflow CuDNNLSTM keras error. TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'time_major')

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, cudnn

After I save a CuDNNLSTM model in tensorflow 1.13.1, I try to load it back immediately to use it.
I get the following error

> TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'time_major').

I looked through the source code for the tensorflow for python and it seems that the `_init__()` for the base class `_CuDNNRNN()` has completely removed `time_major` from being initialized.  
Then why was `time_major` written to file with `model.save()`?

Comment: I changed nothing and ran the code again today, and it works.  I am at a loss as to why.  I didn't even shut my computer off last night.  Same exact state

Comment: I have this problem as well, I'm using plaidml because I don't have a CUDA gpu for tensorflow. I just added time_major to the allowed arguments lol hope it doesn't cause any issue.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the import

```
from keras.models import model_from_json
```

to

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
```

helped in my situation.